# Reputation history should have indents

Tags: feature-request, reputation-history

When I look at a user's detailed reputation history, I see something like this:

[image: Current reputation history]

I find this list confusing to look at, and think it would be best to indent the reputation actions with four spaces (or a 'tab') like this:

[image: Idea: indent actions]

This would make the reputation actions and days stand out more.

To more clearly illustrate what I'm envisioning, here is a mockup by user Makyen:

[image: mockup with actions indented]

Comment: Would [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siXDy.png) be along the lines of what you're looking for (obviously not perfect, but closer)?

Comment: Isn't that more like what it used to look like, @Makyen?

Comment: @Catija I'd have to dig up an image of the old reputation page to compare with, but it's probably closer to the old pages than the new ones. Basically, I wanted something that was substantially more usable than the reputation pages we were left with after the most recent updates (which I find excessively difficult to use, but better than their first revised version). The image is what I see when I view a reputation page. It's mostly CSS changes, but does use some JavaScript too.